# Ajax event always redirect

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc

I have a button with an action :

```
<a id="viewlog" href="" class="btn btn-default" />
```

And :

```
$("#viewlog").bind('click', function (e) {
    $.ajax({
        url: "/Log/FindFile?idTraitement=" + $("#IdTraitement").val(),
        success: function (data) {
            if(data.success == false){
                Lobibox.alert('error', { title: 'Erreur', msg: 'Fichier introuvable' });     
            }
            else
                window.location.href = "/Log/GetTraitementLogs?idTraitement=" + $("#IdTraitement").val();
        },
        error: function (response) {
            Lobibox.alert('error', { title: 'Erreur', msg: response.responseText });
        }
    });
});
```

The action call is this, the idea is if a file is found I return true else false :

```
public JsonResult FindFile(int idTraitement)
{
    string filename = string.Empty;

    try
    {
        filename = new QryTraitementService().GetErrLogFilename(idTraitement);
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        return Json(new { success = false, responseText = e.Message }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }

    return Json(new { success = true }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

and then, if the file is found :

```
public FileResult GetTraitementLogs(int idTraitement)
{
    string filename = new QryTraitementService().GetErrLogFilename(idTraitement);

    return File(filename,"text/csv",filename);
}
```

So, first thing is when I come back to client side with firefox or chrome I go to the `error` in ajax but with IE I go to the success with a var `success` in `data`.

But the big problem is that the function always redirect me to nowhere so I fail in 404. Why the call always redirect me ? Even if I don't pass on a `window.location.href` ?

Comment: You are returning file result in json result type of action method which leads you to exception thus always returning false in view

Comment: No, I return success or not in the first function `FindFile`, if success I go to `GetTraitementLogs` for download the file else I want to show a message. And it works great, the only problem is that when I show the message the page is redirect, so 404...

Comment: Are you running the client portion locally from a file? You could be being caught by the JS security implementation in Chrome and FF. If so try running a local web server and accessing that way.